# What fields are included under AllMetrics for Log Analytics for Azure Functions 2.x

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I want to find out what fields are included for the `AllMetrics` checkbox shown below for `Log Analytics` for `Azure Functions` 2.x.

[image]

Links to MS official website is required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftwebsites-functions) is the Microsoft official documentation to know all the supported metrics of functions.

You may also check all the supported metrics of functions by going to Azure portal -> YOURFUNCTIONAPP -> Platform features -> Monitoring tile -> Metrics -> Click '+ Select a Resource' and make sure you select YOURFUNCTIONAPP -> Click 'Apply' -> Click on drop down list of 'Metrics' to view all the supported metrics of YOURFUNCTIONAPP.

Illustration:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Note: If you think your question has been answered then please 'accept' it, if just helped click "This answer is useful". This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: I cannot see the UI where YOURFUNCTIONAPP can be selected. Can you provide a screenshot for after Click '+ Select a Resource'?

Comment: Added the screenshots in my above answer.